# Select layer by contents

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have a PSD with a lot of layers, that are in a lot of groups. I think it would be very nice if when I click on the element, that layer would automatically be selected. Currently, I have to search for the correct layer in the Layers panel, which is pretty annoying sometimes.

I know there is the CTRL+click feature but, when you use groups, it only selects the group the layer is in, not the layer itself. Is there a way to change this functionality? Is there a way to make it select the layer instead of the group?

Comment: For the most part Photoshop is an image editor, not a vector graphics drawing program, like say, Illustrator is -- so what you want to do doesn't really make sense since it doesn't really have "elements" or individual objects that you can select to edit.

Comment: True, but if you have many adjustment layers with masks, then it's possible for PS to make an educated guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the Move Tool.  Then up in the options bar, there is an "Auto-Select" checkbox.  Check that and it will then attempt to guess which layer you want when you click, based on content.

Based on this thread: [Select Layer not Group](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/570214), there is an additional dropdown option to select group or layer, so try changing that to layer.

[image]

Comment: This is the same functionality as you get with CTRL+click, it goes back to the group the layer is in, instead of selecting the layer.

Comment: Ah, there is another option, can't confirm as I don't have PS at work, but will add to the answer.

Comment: Crazy, it's just next to it, how blind I am! Thanks!